# Issue to deploy safe infrastructure on a new chain

Tags: safe-core-sdk, safe-core

We want to follow the procedure described it here : https://github.com/safe-global/safe-infrastructure

So we started adding our token to safe-deployment repo and request a bump in the NPM package. Done.

But, other libraries / tools still refer to old versions that does not include the newest safe-deployment package.

So, it seems that the whole stack needs to be bumped

is it right ? or do we miss something ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Please note that only the version `v1.3.0` of the contracts is fully supported for all services and infrastructure. Did you try to use this version or `v1.4.1`?

Let me know,
Louis

Comment: We use version 1.3.0 but all repo are not up to date with last deployment (I think we are not the only, and really wondering if any one is able to deploy is own safe infrastructure on his chain for the last 6 months)